# Rig attaching to wrong legs

Tags: rigging

I am following along with a tutorial to rig a cartoon humanoid.

I got to the point where he attaches the rig using "parent with automatic weights", and in the tutorial there are very few major problems. When I attempted it, however, the leg bones (labeled Thigh_R, Thigh_L, Calf_R, and Calf_L) get attached to the wrong leg.

[image: After attaching rig]

I tried to fix it by manually weight painting it, but that heavily deformed the mesh. I was wondering if there was a (preferably simple) way to fix this problem. 
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42247

Comment: that is so odd.

Comment: In the Tutorial, is he using for names: Thigh_L or Thigh.L ? This might be the reason, just might, Blender recognises the Dot relation to distinguish .L for left, .R for right, he should've mentioned this in the tutorial.

Comment: Another possible reason is the mesh itself, automatic weighing is not so automatic, when the mesh is complicated, although this doesn't seems to be the case here

Comment: @Georges he uses underscores in the tutorial, and it works for mirroring the bones, so I don't think there is a problem there. I will try it with the dot though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your model is "inverted".

Try this :

- In object mode : <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> then choose "rotation and scale"
- In edit mode : select all your vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> then replace your normals with <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd>
- Now simply reparent your mesh with the armature

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I did anything like this, but it may be that your rig has the legs flipped in pose mode. (I'm not at my home pc right now so I can't check the blend, will when I get home).

Try zeroing out all transformations in pose mode before parenting the mesh to the armature (make sure to delete the armature modifier on the mesh from the first attempt).

You can do this by selecting each bone in pose mode (using CTRL-A) and the use the following to zero each transform type:
CTRL-R (rotation),
CTRL-S (scale),
CTRL-G (location)

Then try parenting the mesh to the armature again